# call specific fuction of class by url in php

Tags: php, json, function, methods

hy, i have two function in class but i want to call specific function of class by hitting function name in url

```
class RedeemAPI {

    private $db;

    // Constructor - open DB connection
    function __construct() {
        $this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'promos');
        $this->db->autocommit(FALSE);
    }

    // Destructor - close DB connection
    function __destruct() {
        $this->db->close();
    }

    // Main method to redeem a code
    function redeem() {
        echo 'someone is here before';
    }

 function users ()  {
        $array = array();
        $array[0]= "user 1";
        $array[1]= "user 2";
        $array[2]= "user 3";


        sendResponse(200, json_encode($array), 'application/json');
        return true;
    }
}
$api = new RedeemAPI;
$api->redeem();
$api->users();
```

by this code both functions call at same time i am hitting url test/apicall.php/users/

Answer (score 0):

write something.php?function=users in your url

```
...
$function = $_GET['function'];
$api = new RedeemAPI;
$api->$function();
...
```

But this way of calling functionality is very unsecure. Please use it carefully, hope you know what you are doing ;)

If you need url like this: test/apicall.php/users/, please consider using .htaccess for parsing "users" as function variable.

Comment: is there any example if using a parameters too? like something.php?function=users&param1=value1&param2=value2